# How to divide array in FlatList and Text in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I put first line of the array

> "id":"1","name":"Some Name","bal":"1000"

in a `<Text>{name} {balance}</Text>`
and then other 2 lines in a `<FlatList />`. I am able to either display FlatList or Text by fetching the array but not both. I am able to display the desired outcome if I make another screen put the first line in  and then import it in second screen. But I think there is a better way to divide this array in single screen and display Text and FlatList. Thanks.

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Some Name",
      "bal": "1000",
      "ab": "1000"
    }
  ],
  {
    "area": "North",
    "building": "Some Building",
    "unit_number": "123"
  },
  {
    "area": "North",
    "building": "Some Building",
    "unit_number": "123"
  }
]
```

UPDATE: kindly see the code. Where I have commented out the line that is where I need to extract and display the first line of array in

```
export default class ClientDetails extends Component {


    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
           isLoading: true
        }
    }
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
     <View>
    <Text>
       {item.area}
       </Text>
       <Text>
        Rent Amount:  {item.building}
        </Text>
       <Text>
        Rent Amount:  {item.unit_number}
        </Text>
    </View>
        )
      }
    componentDidMount = () => {
    return fetch("http://192.168.0.106/db_1/list.php?id=1")
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson,
                })
            })
    }
    render() {
return (
       <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

//Here I was to put <Text> {id}{name}{bal}</Text> but I can either get <Text> to display or <FlatList>
  <FlatList
            data={ this.state.dataSource }
               ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.renderSeparator}
     renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
 </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not understand your intent, could you describe it clearly and give an example image

Comment: The array you've written in the question is not valid?

Comment: As @VigneshVPai said, your array has not an appropriate shape.

Comment: @in.k, but I can either get <Text> to display or <FlatList>, what is this meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out client info for FlatList in your `renderItem`. In your case, this might work:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  if (item.area != null){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
        {item.area}
        </Text>
        <Text>
         Rent Amount:  {item.building}
         </Text>
        <Text>
         Rent Amount:  {item.unit_number}
         </Text>
     </View>
    )
  } 
}

render() {
  const data = this.state.dataSource

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      { data && data[0] && data[0][0] ?
      <Text>{data[0][0].id} {data[0][0].name} {data[0][0].bal}</Text> : null }
      <FlatList
        data={ data }
        ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.renderSeparator}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: But the data is dynamically fetched through url. How can i define using your suggested const data to dynamically get the data? Thanks

Comment: Dynamically as if the array could be empty? If possible, can you list out the possible data sources (eg best/worst case scenario, which data is fixed) so I can try to give a better solution.

Comment: No the data cannot be empty. I meant in your code where you mentioned the const data = []. that is the data you are inputting manually. I mean once the data is fetch as you can see in the original post from url and there is response, how do I put that data in your **const data**

Comment: I see. Based on your original post, you can replace the `data` with `this.state.dataSource` from your `responseJson` in `ComponentDidMount`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Getting error undefined is not an object for data[0]. If I remove this line the flatlist is output fine.

Comment: I think it's either because the data is not yet loaded OR your `responseJson` structure is not the same as the sample json data you posted above. If it's the first case, then `render()` is called first before `ComponentDidMount`, fyi. So try doing a check for data to see if it's null before reading the data `<Text>{data && data[0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0].id} </Text>`

Comment: Thanks very much for quick reply. I think we are getting there. using <Text>{data && data[0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0].id} </Text> I get the client id correctly and then the FlatList is output. If I change id to name I get the name of the client correctly. I tried to put the render before componentDidMount() but that just produces blank screen

Comment: Yes, because it's React lifecycle. CDM will be executed after render(), that's the rule. If you want your API be called before render() then previously we had `ComponentWillMount()` but now it's deprecated. Have no chance yet to explore the alternatives. But you can read here for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html. Please accept my answer if it helps!

Comment: Thanks. so you are saying to get the id. I have to write <Text>{data && data[0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0].id} </Text> then another <Text></Text> for the name and so on. Because putting render() before componentDidMount() give a blank page

Comment: <Text>{data && data[0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0].id}</Text>
<Text>{data && data[0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0].name}</Text>
<Text>{data && data[0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0] && data[0][0].bal}</Text> gives me the results at least

Comment: It can be simplified. I've updated my answer. I'm sure there's better way to do it but that's what I can think of now.

Comment: Yes it is working, thank you, but I think to style each it is better to use different <Text>. Also I tried render() before componentDidMount() also worked. I don't know what happened before maybe expo issue. Thanks again really helped.

Comment: Yes you're right. You can put those <Text/> inside <View/> in the if else statement

Answer (score 0):

you can put the static data in that particular arrays first item . else if you want same static data the use SectionList and use renderSectionHeader props to use the static element.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't want if else etc.. I want <Text> and <FlatList> items both. FlatList display properties and Text display client details

Comment: use SectionList and header item i think you will get your thing

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I can either get FlatList if I use dataSource: responseJson, or if I change it to eg. cn: responseJson.name, balance: responseJson.bal then I get Text.

Comment: I don't want header I need to display client details wrapped in View and Text on screen as there can be more details for the clients not just balance and name

Answer (score 0):

you can save the data in different state props, not make it in props. I hope the following code can match your problem

```
constructor(props){
  this.state = {
     isLoad:false,
     listData:[],
     idInfo:{}
  }
}

render(){
<View>
<this.state.idInfo && this.state.dataList.length == 0 && <Text>{this.state.idInfo.name}</Text>
<this.state.dataList.lenght>0 && <FlatList/>
<View>
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    // I suggest you request in different methods, the according to the 
   //return data, update the state 
    return fetch("http://192.168.0.106/db_1/list.php?id=1")
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                if("responseJson is list"){
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    listData: responseJson,
                })}
               if("respnseJson is the id you say"){
                  this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    idInfo: responseJson,
                })}
               }
            })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Looking at your code just consider that there is no if else statement. I want to return both of them. First I want to return <Text> having id, name, balance and then I want to return the <FlatList> having list of the client properties.

Comment: the item is rendered by index,  if you want to the array first element show then the rest of elements, but the first element view is different from the rest, it can satisfy your require

Comment: @ in.k , I understand you want every when the item is{name,..},then render the text.I think you firstly have to split the array which match the secionlist data, then use the sectionlist

Comment: I tried to adjust your code and removing the if else but the issue is still not resolved. I think how the setup is now for me I will keep it which is importing the first part from another screen. The only issue is if there are different data fetching different info for the same client it would keep on adding new screens for each data. Anyway thanks very much for your help

Comment: @ in.k, I update the answer, if you want to render items according to different item data. if you want to according to differnt sourceData, you can use `< "some condition" && <View>"some view you want to render"</View>`

Comment: Thanks for that but as I mentioned there are no conditions. Lets say the array starts by getting info of client by id from database and then query calculates the balance and available balance and address, phone etc. Now this info is not a Flatlist but just may a Text wrapped in view. so this is the first info then the query puts properties that this client has and makes a FlatList. Then may be info about paymens made etc etc. This can be used by fetching from url in react. So the whole screen is not if else but displaying data in different components <FlatList></Text> etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201531/discussion-between-lenoarod-and-in-k).

Comment: Thanks. Again there is no IF ELSE. There is going to be data that is client specific and there is data that is properties' specific